# Not able to submit or not submit form after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form after validation and confirmation. But after the validation the form is not getting submitted. If I do not validate and confirm then the form is being submitted. What am I doing wrong here? Please tell me how to rectify it.

```
<div class="button secondary" id="contact_submit">
  Create/Update <span class="icon-right icon-check"></span>
</div>



function validateFields() {

  #some validation operations

  if(validated){
     if(operation == "Create"){
          $("#contact-form")[0].setAttribute("action", "/contact/create_contact/");
          $("#contact-form")[0].setAttribute("method", "POST");
        }
        else if(operation == "Update"){
          $("#contact-form")[0].setAttribute("action", "/contact/" + object_id + "/update_contact/");
          $("#contact-form")[0].setAttribute("method", "PATCH");
        }

        $('#contact-form').on('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url: '/oms/getIsPrimaryContact/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { object_id: object_id },
            success: function(data) {
              if ($('.element-contact#is_primary_contact').prop("checked") && !data.is_primary_contact) {
                var c = confirm('Are you sure you want to change the primary contact?');
                if (c) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              }
            },
            error: function() {} });
        });

        $('#contact-form').submit();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contact_submit").click(function(e) {
    validateFields()
  });
});
```

It just shows the confirmation box and if I click on `ok` or `cancel` then also the ajax call is being initiated. If the checkbox is not checked then also the form is not being submitted.
On clicking either button in the confirmation box the form should be submitted or not submitted and if the checkbox is not checked then the form should just be submitted.
But instead ajax call is happening on clicking any button.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form from being submitted, which you add once it is validated.

Comment: If I add `e.preventDefault()` inside `success` function then the form is getting submitted always even if I click on `cancel` in confirmation box.

Comment: Yes, because you trigger `$('#contact-form').submit()` either way. You only have to trigger it on `success` and unbind the ajax call from the submit event, since it creates a circle. It is best to draw all processes on a sheet of paper (flowchart) and after turn it into code.